# Pyplot Labelposition Y-axis in Julia

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, julia

I basically want the Y label (using PyPlot) on the right side with it's ticks. For Python I found the comand `ax.yaxis.set_label_position("right")`.

But if I do

```
ax=gca()
ax.yaxis.set_label_position("right")
```

or `ax[:yaxis](label_position="right")`

Julia says "type PyObject has no field yaxis" for the first case and "TypeError("'YAxis' object is not callable",)" for the second case. How do I adress it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write:

```
gca()[:yaxis][:set_label_position]("right")
```

to get what you want